# How to load content of ReactStrap Tab when it's selected or active?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, reactstrap

I am using ReactJS and ReactStrap to create tabs on my page.
When I open the page containing the tabs, the components of all the tabs-content is mounted on the page load but I want the component to load when that particular tab is active.
[My Code](https://github.com/Samy-33/OzonePP/blob/bc2fadc161876e1d0603ce809a39c56ec9540b47/ui/src/contests/contest-detail.jsx#L153)

[ReactStrap Tab Example](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tabs/)

Answer (score 8):

Below is the modified code snippet from ReactStrap Tab example. Look for the content inside `<TabPane></TabPane>`.

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: '1'
    };
  }

  toggle(tab) {
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
      this.setState({ activeTab: tab });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav tabs>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '1' })}
              onClick={() => { this.toggle('1'); }}>
              Tab1
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '2' })}
              onClick={() => { this.toggle('2'); }}>
              Moar Tabs
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
        <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
          <TabPane tabId="1">
            { this.state.activeTab == 1 ? <h4>Tab 1 Contents</h4> : null }
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane tabId="2">
            { this.state.activeTab == 2 ? <h4>Tab 2 Contents</h4> : null }
          </TabPane>
        </TabContent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you style the NavLink/NavItem by className using CSS in this case?